# Sanitize apex and user input

Tags: php

I'm trying to sanitize user input in PHP for saving data in a query. The problem are special chars like `'` or `"`.

I tried with `htmlspecialchars()`, `addslashes()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` but they aren't working. What's the best and fast way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: That's not really for SQL injection but only to save special char of a textarea

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments, so that everything is in one place. Can you explain more clearly what you want to do? First you say "sanitize input", which I read as removing special characters, then your comment says you to save special characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use APEX_ESCAPE package to "sanitize" your data. Try the below

```
select apex_escape.html_whitelist('<h1>Hello<script>alert("XSS");</script></h1>') from dual;
```